# Iimport a folder from another folder

Tags: python, directory

Is it like:

```
from <folder1>, <folder2>, import <file>
```

Or its not possible I guess?

Comment: `from <folder1>.<folder2> import <file>`

Comment: You should read up on the import/module system of python: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily add the paths of all the folders containing the python modules you want to import to the sys.path. Say for example you had a python module called file1.py in a folder folder1 located in the parent directory of your working directory, you can import it as follows:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../folder1")
sys.path.append("../folder2")
import file1
import file2
```

Answer (score -1):

Using an absolute path might be the easiest thing to do.
eg:
C:\Users\exampleUser\Documents\folder1\folder2\file

Would this be suitable for your application?